# Cookie does not persist across redirect in production

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers

I'm building a web application that uses cookies to track the user session. These cookies work flawlessly in development on localhost but they aren't working correctly in production. I suspect this is because I have some cookie settings misconfigured but I'm not sure which.

One thing to note is that the webapp runs at `app.goldsky.com` and the api runs at `api.goldsky.io` (note the different TLDs).

The application I'm building uses a tool called [WorkOS](https://workos.com/) for user authentication.

The authentication flow is as follows:

1. User visits website, enters their email and presses the login button
2. Request is sent to backend (`api.goldsky.io`)
3. Backend generates an authentication URL using the WorkOS SDK (of the form `api.workos/...`) and sends this to the frontend
4. the frontend navigates to this WorkOS authentication URL and proceeds through the auth flow
5. If successful, WorkOS redirects the user to my backend (`api.goldsky.io/auth/workos/callback`)
6. My backend generates a session token, sets a secure, httpOnly, path=`/` cookie with the session token (`goldsky_session=...`) and redirects the user back to the webapp (`app.goldsky.com`)

In localhost this all works flawlessly. However, in production I don't see the cookie persist after step 6 completes.

In production, the response to step 5 contains the cookie

[image]

however after the redirect back to the webapp, the cookie seems to disappear. Here's the request to `app.goldsky.com` (the redirect from step 6) and it doesn't have the cookie header.

[image]

and just for completeness, here's a screenshot of the cookies for `app.goldsky.com` - it's empty:

[image]

By comparison, the final redirect on localhost contains the cookie:

[image]

How come my cookie does not persist after redirecting from `api.goldsky.io` to `app.goldsky.com`? Do I need to set the `Domain` attribute for the cookie? If so, what should I set it to? Maybe this is a `SameSite` problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an nginx misconfiguration issue which was rejecting requests to specific paths. Nginx was only allowing requests to `/auth` and a few others. My login logic was under `/auth` but the user query was at `/user` which nginx was rejecting.